# Accepting quotes in user text input field

Tags: objective-c

I have this bit of code that accepts a user inputted string.  It works unless the user enters double quotes " "

```
if([variableValue isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        input=[input stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"set %@ to (\"%@\" as text)\n",variableName,variableValue,nil]];
```

I tried this code but it doesn't seem to work...

```
if([variableValue isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        NSString *stringValue = (NSString *) variableValue;
        stringValue=[stringValue stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
        input=[input stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"set %@ to (\"%@\" as text)\n",variableName,stringValue,nil]];
```

...and I'm banging my head against the desk... any thoughts?  Where am I going wrong, is this the best approach to solving this pain in the...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the text in a textfield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a UITextfield, you shouldn't have to do anything special... I just used the below code in a new UIViewController:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(test)];

    self.textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80, 300, 30)];
    self.textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.textField];
}

- (void)test {
    NSLog(@"%@", self.textField.text);
}
```

I typed in the following (including ALL single and double quotes) "This is " a 'test' ""." and the result in the console was:

"This is " a 'test' ""."